# Envio de notificações SNS na Amazon com Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, mobile, amazon-aws, sns

Ao executar o método ->sns->publish tenho o seguinte erro:

```
Error executing "Publish" on "https://sns.us-west-2.amazonaws.com"; AWS HTTP error: Client error: `POST https://sns.us-west-2.amazonaws.com` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response:

<ErrorResponse xmlns="http://sns.amazonaws.com/doc/2010-03-31/">
    <Error>
        <Type>Sender</Type>
        <Code>InvalidPara (truncated...)
 InvalidParameter (client): Invalid parameter: TargetArn Reason: ARN specifies an invalid endpointId: UUID must be encoded in exactly 36 characters. - 
            <ErrorResponse xmlns="http://sns.amazonaws.com/doc/2010-03-31/">
                <Error>
                    <Type>Sender</Type>
                    <Code>InvalidParameter</Code>
                    <Message>Invalid parameter: TargetArn Reason: ARN specifies an invalid endpointId: UUID must be encoded in exactly 36 characters.</Message>
                </Error>
                <RequestId>a634effa-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-bfeb15b8XXXX</RequestId>
            </ErrorResponse>
```

Efetuando vários testes e debugando os valores das variáveis, eu imprimo a variável que armazena o codarn do cliente ($target) e ela está OK.
Cheguei a copiar o valor da variável e em seguida colocar diretamente no método a qual implemento o envio e **funcionou normalmente**.
Somente quando passo o valor como parâmetro o erro acontece.
Esse é meu método implementado:

```
public function publishMessage($target, $message) {
        try {            
            $result = $this->sns->publish([
                'MessageStructure' => 'json',
                'Message' => $message,
                'TargetArn' => $target,
            ]);
        } catch (\Aws\Sns\Exception\SnsException $exc) {
            echo $exc->getMessage();
            return false;
        }
        return $result;
    }
```

PS: os XXX no RequestId é proposital e para manter sigiloso o valor do codarn do cliente.

Answer (score 0):

Durante todo o tempo que usei o serviço de notificações da AWS, sempre selecionei a região **us-west-2**. Inclusive atualmente tenho várias aplicações utilizando essa região.

Dessa vez ao criar a aplicação apareceu esse problema até um pouco bizarro. Sem nenhuma explicação plausível ou que pudesse esclarecer o ocorrido, me restaram duas alternativas:

1. A região não aceita mais novas aplicações e ou estava apresentando instabilidade no momento OU
2. A região somente aceita a utilização no modo SAND_BOX.

Lembrando que o envio ocorria normalmente quando efetuado manualmente e ou quando era inserido o valor do Endpoint ARN direto no código.

Eu estou utilizando o lumen/laravel 5.2, o SDK na versão mais recente até essa data e a solução do problema veio quando **criei outra aplicação em outra região**.